# Why is java.util.concurrent.FutureTask not serializable

Tags: java, spring, wicket, java.util.concurrent

I am currently using Apache Wicket. I have some REST calls which take a few seconds each. Wicket allows ajax calls synchronously only, so I was trying to use Future and Callable.

This is part of my class:

```
public abstract class GetPrices extends AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
        private List<Future<List<Result>>> list;

        public GetPrices(Duration updateInterval, List<Callable> priceCalls) {
           super(updateInterval);
           list = new ArrayList<Future<List<Result>>>();

           ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(priceCalls.size());
           for(Callable callable : priceCalls) {
               list.add(executor.submit(callable));
           }
           executor.shutdown();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            while(list.hasNext()) {
                Future<List<Result>> future = listIterator.next();
                if(future.isDone()) {
                    List<Result> data = future.get();
                    //Process data
                }
            }
        }
    //Error handling etc
}
```

The `List<Callable> priceCalls` contains the method calls to the appropriate price calls

I receive The object type is not Serializable! against java.util.concurrent.FutureTask list field

I am assuming I should design this differently. Could any provide any thoughts on how this should be done?

I am using Spring if that helps

Comment: It makes no sense to serialize a `FutureTask` because you would need to serialize the complete context of it which can include arbitrary resources; most importantly a `Thread` instance - how would you serialize a Thread? Answer: you can't; at least not in java. Also, I believe this is an XY problem - what exactly do you want to achieve by serializing a `FutureTask` instance?

Comment: What @l4mpi says: it makes no sense at all to serialize such an object. A `FutureTask` is not an invariant of a class in any case. If you have such a field in a class you want to serialize, make it `transient`. Note that in the "makes no sense" department, `Reentrant*Lock` classes _are_ `Serializable`...

Comment: I have now added further details to my problem as it is clear how I thought I would be able to solve this is not really possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Spring's Async and AjaxLazyLoadPanel

See more info here: 
http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/AjaxLazyLoadPanel-loading-asynchronously-td4664035.html#a4665188

Answer (score 2):

`FutureTask` isn't serializable because it depends on other resources like an `Executor`, probably a `Thread` instance, a `Queue` and OS resources which can't be easily serialized.

Comment: Is it possible for it to be serializable? If so, are there any examples around to implement this?

Comment: There is no way to serialize anything that implements `Future` directly. A workaround is to create an object which contains all the data necessary to submit the task again later and serialize that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be create your own implementation of Future, which also implements Serializable.

In the page below, the author shows that. In this case, he used JMS behind the Future implementation.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/implementing-custom-future.html