# Future Object serialized on complex object

Tags: java, object, serialization, future, complextype

I want to have a Future object returned from a thread pool, which has complex attributes. Should I use the serializable interface for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't make it `Serializable` unless you actually want to serialize it. In Java built-in `ExecutorService`s do not involve serialization.

Comment: Thank you sir! @bedrin Is there any reason why serialization should not be involved to `ExecutorService` ? Does it cause any problems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375764/why-is-java-util-concurrent-futuretask-not-serializable is a pretty similiar problem to mine and gives most of the answer.